# PHP exec() not storing Process ID

Tags: php, linux, process, exec

I have a PHP program which is starting a process in the background via exec() (the output of the process is being sent to /dev/null). I then use `exec("echo $!", $processes[0])` because I want to store the ID of the process so I can terminate it later. However, the result of `$processes[0]` is an empty array.

Why is the process ID not being stored? Note that the process ID is outputted correctly if I execute my background process and then run `echo $!` from the terminal. An additional note is that I am using a Raspberry Pi which is Linux-based.

Comment: The second `exec()` runs a new shell process, which has no knowledge of the previous ones´ `$!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to record the process ID, you have to set it into a variable.  For example, to start another PHP script in the background:

```
$pid = exec("php mysbackgroundscript.php >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");
```

The $pid variable should then contain the PID.